# My own Trello, moving cards from one list to another

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

In the first place, I must say that I am the beginning.

I'm trying to create a project that looks just like Trello, before I will start I need to know, how to do in database in MongoDB(Mongoose) table with blackboard, lists, cards(tasks).

If i make 3 separate tables, How i do later using javascript drag and drop move the card from top to bottom in the list and between the lists in the step in which I wants. I mean it how do i do that when i move the card from one list to the other in the middle of the card it will update everything and save it in the database.

I would like somebody to explain me how to do it I will be very grateful.